# Facebook Like Box not working for specific facebook page

Tags: facebook, embed, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to embed a facebook like box to my website and am using the facebook developer like box too. I find that when pasting in the facebook page no activity, posts or anything appears in the box.

I've tried testing using different facebook pages and it works fine for those. Just not the facebook I want.

I'm really not sure why the facebookpage is https://www.facebook.com/thelopesarms?fref=ts

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Clear all your cache.
It's like a recent problem on like-box. But after I fixed with this, my plugin shows one more face than before :S